# Python checking for serial string in If statement

Tags: python, linux, serial-port

As a newbie to python, I'm trying to use it to read a file and write each line of the file to the RS-232 port. My code bellow seems to work for the most part, except for my listen and react segments. From poking around, it seems that my if statements can't read if I've received a "Start\r", or "End\r" string from my device (RS-232). Can anyone provide feedback on what is missing?

```
import serial
import time

port = "/dev/ttyS0"
speed = 9600

print("\n\n\n\nScript Starting\n\n\n")

ser = serial.Serial(port, speed, timeout=0) 

ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output and discard all that is in buffer

text_file = open("my.file", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
i = 0
counter = 0


while i<len(lines):

    response = ser.readline()

    if (counter == 0):
        print("\n\nProbing With Off Data\n")
        ser.write('FFF')
        ser.write('\r')
        counter+=1

    if (response == 'Start'):

        ser.write('FFF')
        ser.write('\r')

    if (response == 'End'):
        print("\nString Transmitted:")
        print lines
        make_list_a_string = ''.join(map(str, lines))
        ser.write(make_list_a_string)
        ser.write('\r')
        print("\n")
        i+=1




text_file.close()
exit(0)
```

Comment: What error or incorrect behaviour do you get? If you get an exception, please post the full stack trace. What do you want to happen? Also, some basic debugging is a good idea - what values do you get in `response` - add in a `print()` and tell us how it differs from what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strip() to get rid of any trailing or preceding '\r's:

```
if (response.strip() == 'Start'):
```