# Serial read in Python escape symbols

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Hello friends I need write some script to measure low power on Arduino analog pin and read it on my computer in Python. I write simple script what allow me to read serial data from USB no problem in this I get reading in range 0.00 - 25.00, equal power on analog pin, but I cant make script show me data how I wish.

```
import serial
import time
import sys
#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600) # Linux
ser = serial.Serial('COM13', 9600, timeout=0) # Windows
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while True:
  data1 = ser.readline()

  if data1 == 2.54:
      print ("low")

  elif data1 == 2.69:
      print ("hi")

  elif data1 == 2.57:
      print ("center")

  else:
      print (data1)
      time.sleep(1)
```

Some thing I write wrong and script not show me low, center, hi, value then its reached.

Answer (score 0):

Having `if data1 == 2.54` is a very limited range in my experience the values will jump around a bit unless you have your Arduino perform some rounding and have it send the value 2.54 else it would be better to use a `>=`. To decode the received data you can use `data1.decode()` this will stop you getting the encoded string in the format b'10\r\n' and will instead give you 10. 
here is how i would write the code.

```
data1 = ser.readline()
data1 = data1.decode()
if data1 >= 20:
    print ("high")

elif data1 >= 15:
    print ("medium")

elif data1 >= 10:
    print ("low")

else:
    print("the value is below 10")
    print (data1)
  time.sleep(1)
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution if some one need it :

```
if (data1.strip() == '2.54'):
```

works for me perfect , the answer find here : [Python checking for serial string in If statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121781/python-checking-for-serial-string-in-if-statement) , Big thanks to #micromoses